# C++ how to fix struct header_t has no member 's'

Tags: c++, c, struct

I have a program in C which contains multiple structs

```
struct header_t {
    size_t size;
    unsigned is_free;
    struct header_t *next;
};

typedef char ALIGN[16];

union header {
    struct {
        size_t size;
        unsigned is_free;
        union header *next;
    } s;
    ALIGN stub;
};
typedef union header header_t;


header_t *head, *tail;
...
```

In C this program works correctly but when I try to add this struct to C++ I get the error that `The struct header_t has no member 's'`

How can I fix this so it works in C++ too?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe in C++ you cannot have a single identifier (`header_t`) that refers to two different entities (a `struct` and a type alias). Didn't you get any compiler error or warning? Live demo of such one: https://godbolt.org/z/zr8zPjaee.

Comment: See this: [struct tags in C++ are even weirder](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/struct-tags-in-c-are-even-weirder/)

Comment: @DanielLangr: You definitely can have those two identifiers in C++. It's a continuing headache for the C++ committee to keep that working in new C++ standards, but even in C++20 it's still allowed.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> struct header_t //...
> typedef union header header_t;
> ```

In C++, this is ill-formed, as the type names conflict.

You must give either the class, or the type alias another name, since both cannot have the name `header_t`. Or you have to put one of them inside a namespace.

Another problem, you must include the header that defines `size_t`.

After those fixes, the shown program will be well-formed C++ and will compile with a conforming compiler.

Comment: do you have any suggestion how to resolve the conflict, I cannot get my head around it

Comment: @nad34 `do you have any suggestion how to resolve the conflict` Choose another name for one of them. I think changing the name of the class will be simpler.

Comment: so `typedef union header somename;` would do the trick. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @nad34 Sure. You would then have to change anything that was using that type alias to use the new name.

Comment: @nad34: I suggest you are better off changing `struct header_t` to `struct OtherName` rather than changing `typedef union header header_t;` to `typedef union header OtherName;`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is ill-formed. See 6.5.1 [basic.lookup.general], in particluar [Note 4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.general#note-4). You can refer to `struct header_t` using the _Elaborated type specifier_ `struct header_t`; see 6.5.6.

Comment: @MSalters See [[diff.dcl](https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.dcl#3)]

Comment: @eerorika: That is in an informative (non-normative) section. Violating it does not make a program ill-formed, since informative sections are not controlling.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sure, but it's the easiest way to understand the difference. Unless there is a normative rule contradicting the appendix, I see no reason to assume it to be incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

> How can I fix this so it works in C++

It is very easy. All you need for this is not to write such a bad code. That is enough.

If these two declarations

```
struct header_t {
    size_t size;
    unsigned is_free;
    struct header_t *next;
};
```

and

```
typedef union header header_t;
```

are declared in the same scope and in the same compilation unit then the C++ compiler should issue an error message saying that there are conflicting declarations.

Otherwise the compiler sees only one declaration

```
struct header_t {
    size_t size;
    unsigned is_free;
    struct header_t *next;
};
```

in a current compilation unit and as result the member `s` is indeed absent in the structure declaration.

Use another identifier instead of `header_t` in the typedef declaration and also in the union declaration instead of the identifier `header`. Otherwise in any case they are confusing relative to the name `header_t` used in the structure declaration.